# Check out working copy to existing files

Tags: svn, cornerstone

I don't have a working copy. Just imported the files from the server and did some changes. Is it possible to check out a working copy to existing local files and be able to commit the changes I made?

Answer (score 1):

> imported the files from the server

WHAT?!

> Is it possible to check out a working copy to existing local files

No. And any SVN documentation clearly states it: you can checkout into empty dir only. You have:

- Checkout repository into any another location
- Integrate your changes into WC
- Commit changes

---

- Forget about own brainless "workflow"

Answer (score 1):

Nope. But you can check out a working copy, then copy your changes over the top of it.

You'd just better hope the server had the latest version of the files, and you're not overwriting other people's changes.

You're using version control wrong. Start using a working copy.